# layouts in nativeScript + transperent background

Tags: android, css, layout, nativescript

I am trying to align some elements in my stackLayout tag.

`<StackLayout #container >
   <Button [text]'Sign in'(tap)="submit()"></Button>
</StackLayout>`

Also, I have a page class which renders image in the background of this stack layout.

When I run , this Images is seen as background but there is white box of stack layout inside which button is seen. which is also expected.
I want stack Layout to have transparent background, so that it looks like button is kept on the image. 
I tried setting opacity of the stack Layout,but it dims the button too. 
Is there any solution for this? or is there any other container I should use instead of stack Layout.
Please help!